# Meaning of "ausgeschlagen"

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

I am trying to understand what *ausgeschlagen* means. On Duden I couldn't find any example that would help me to imagine it really. Could you give me some examples in which this word would fit? What would you describe with it?
As I understood it means something like *covered*, for example for a book that has a cover I would say:

> ein ausgeschlagenes Buch
>   ein ausgeschlagen Buch

Is the word appropriate?

PS: I am not quite sure about how to write that: *ausgeschlagenes* or *ausgeschlagen*? When the adjective ends with an *-en* (also *verlassen*, for example), what should I say:

> *ein verlassen Gebäude*
>   *ein verlassenes Gebäude*

Comment: http://kleinanzeigen.ebay.de/anzeigen/s-anzeige/weide-rattan-korb-27-cm-mit-stoff-ausgeschlagen-neu/277497350-18-1444

Comment: Bücher hingegen können einen Einschlag haben. http://www.atelierstrebel.ch/2_umschlag.shtml

Comment: Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausschlagen -> which examples are unclear?

Comment: But she explicitly said "ausgeschlagen", the book-example is from OP. So either she needs a word for wrapping a book (->See Carsten Schultz' comment), or clarification on "ausgeschlagen". Im waiting for more input before venturing an answer...

Comment: Sorry to be confusing and not explicit. I actually need to know what the adjective means and how to declinate it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declination (m/f/n singular; plural):

> Nominativ: der/die/das ausgeschlagene; die ausgeschlagenen 
>   Genitiv: des/der/des ausgeschlagenen; der ausgeschlagenen 
>   Dativ: dem/der/dem ausgeschlagenen; den ausgeschlagenen
>   Akkusativ: den ausgeschlagenen/die ausgeschlagene/das ausgeschlagene; den ausgeschlagenen

"Ausgeschlagen" or "[ausschlagen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausschlagen)" has multiple meanings, I'll try and work with the Duden examples (below, grouping by me):

- Describing a rapid, forceful movement (Duden 1-4, 6):
  either a kicking horse (1), some kind of hitting  or beating (2,4,6) or vigorous shake (3). The syllable "aus-" gives an outward movement (1,2,3), a widening or stretching (6) or "off (the opposite of "on") (4).
- Rejection (7):
  Figurative speech analogous to above, according to Duden possibly fencing term. "aus-" stating an outward movement.
- The appearance of something new (9,10), an efflorescence: 
  New leaves on branches, crystaline compounds on walls. The noun "ausschlag "(rash) falls into this category, too.-
  Again, the syllable "aus-" gives an outward movement.
- Describing a change of state, based on some "neutral" position (8,11):
  The movement of a pointer, registering a degree of change or the final meassurement (figuratively for 11). "aus-" means away from (the neutral or zero position).
- Lining or covering the interior of something with fabric (5):
  "aus" denotes the interior, covering from outside would be "ein-", hence a book is "eingeschlagen", a basket "ausgeschlagen".
- Stopping to beat (12):
   "aus-" here meaning having stopped/finished a prior action.

---

The various meanings according to Duden:

> 1. (gewöhnlich von Pferden) nach jemandem schlagen, stoßen
> 2. durch einen Schlag gewaltsam entfernen
> 3. (landschaftlich) durch eine schlagende Handbewegung von etwas befreien
> 4. durch Schlagen ersticken
> 5. mit Stoff auskleiden
> 6. (Handwerk) breit schlagen, hämmern
> 7. ablehnen, zurückweisen
> 8. aus dem Ruhe- oder Gleichgewichtszustand geraten
>          einen Ausschlag anzeigen
> 9. neue Triebe hervorbringen
> 10. (selten) austreten
>         (selten) etwas austreten lassen, ausschwitzen
> 11. sich entwickeln, zu etwas werden
> 12. aufhören zu schlagen

Answer (score 0):

Ein Buch kann "aufgeschlagen" (opened) sein, aber nicht "ausgeschlagen".

Man kann einen Behälter (container, box) innen mit Papier oder Stoff (paper or fabric) ausschlagen (to line). Dann ist der Behälter (z.B. eine Schachtel) mit Papier/Stoff **ausgeschlagen**. Das bedeutet, dass man den Behälter innen mit diesem Material ausgekleidet hat.

Das Lager eines Rades (axle bearing) kann **ausgeschlagen** (worn out) sein. Dann ist das Lager beschädigt, und das Rad läuft nicht mehr ganz rund.

Wenn man von jemandem ein Angebot (offer) erhalten hat, dieses Angebot aber ablehnt (reject), dann hat man das Angebot **ausgeschlagen** (rejected).

Es gibt noch viele weitere Beispiele für das Wort »ausgeschlagen«, an dem man noch mehr unterschiedliche Bedeutungen zeigen kann.

---

Richtig ist:

Neuutrum:

> Das verlassene Gebäude. Das aufgeschlagene Buch. (The left building. The opened book - definite article)
>   Ein verlassenes Gebäude. Ein aufgeschlagenes Buch (A left building. An opened book - indefinite article)

Masculin:

> Der verlassene Schuppen. Der aufgeschlagene Roman. (The left shed. The opened novel - definite article)
>   Ein verlassener Schuppen. Ein aufgeschlagener Roman (A left shed. An opened novel - indefinite article)

Feminin:

> Die verlassene Hütte. Die aufgeschlagene Novelle. (The left hut. The opened novella - definite article)
>   Eine verlassene Hütte. Eine aufgeschlagene Novelle (A left hut. An opened novella - indefinite article)